# Access to std::any in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, c++17

Is there any way to gain access to the:

```
#include <any>
```

library in visual studios 2015?

Or am I going to have to upgrade to VS2017 for C++17 support.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @PeteBecker : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'any': No such file or directory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot use `<any>` in MSVS 2015.  According to the matrix on [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/) `<any>` is not available until MSVS 2017

Comment: Correct. ``<any>`` is part of the C++17 draft, not C++11 or C++14.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/any.html) with a lot of compilers. MSVC 2015 is in the compatibility list. boost::any is header only library and quite stable.